# SVG circuit breaker/switch close animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, css-transforms

I am trying to design a circuit breaker/switch which closes and opens on certain events. I have designed the breaker using SVG and using css animation and transform properties to animate the closing of it.

Using **transform-origin: bottom** but its not working as desired. Please help me following is my css code:

```
.closeme {
    -webkit-animation-name: closeanimaton;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    -webkit-transform-origin: bottom;
    animation-name: closeanimaton;
    animation-duration: 3s; 
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: -1.5s;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    transform-origin: bottom;
    -moz-animation: none;
}

@-webkit-keyframes closeanimaton { 
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(35deg); }
}

@keyframes closeanimaton { 
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(35deg); }
}
```

here is codepen link where i have the whole code, please feel free to edit:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQexEP

Answer (score 0):

This might not be what you have asked help for, but I find it alot easier to work with D3 to create the shapes and add animation to them. Check out my snippet below. It might give you an inspiration on how you may want to do the SVG animation.

```js
var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg").attr("width",200).attr("height",150);
svg.style("background-color","black");



var part1 = svg.append("path").attr("d","M100,0 L100,30").attr("fill","none").attr("stroke","white");

var part2 = svg.append("path").attr("d","M100,80 L100,150").attr("fill","none").attr("stroke","white");

var moving_part = svg.append("g").attr("transform","translate(100,80) rotate(45)");

moving_part.append("path").attr("d","M0,0 L0,-50").attr("fill","none").attr("stroke","gold").attr("stroke-width",2);
moving_part.append("circle").attr("cy",-50).attr("r",5).attr("fill","gold");

moving_part.transition().delay(1000).duration(3000).attr("transform","translate(100,80) rotate(0)");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No i need a solution without **d3**, just with **svg** and **css** animations